# jQuery how to make the ajax request "synchronous" when async is true

Tags: php, jquery, progress-bar

```
var tds = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];

for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {

    jQuery("#notification-bar").html('I am doing ' + tds[i]);

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/ajax_json_echo/",
        type: "POST",
        timeout: 10000,
        data: tds[i],
        success: function(response) {
       
        },
        error: function(x, t, m) {
        
 
        }
    });


} //end for

jQuery("#notification-bar").html("Done!");​
```

/ajax_json_echo/ might take 10 seconds or even more to deal with tds.

The expected result of notification bar is

> I am doing 0
>
> I am doing 1
>
> I am doing 2
>
> ...
>
> Done!

The actual result I get is:

> Done!

I guess it is caused by the async variable of jquery ajax is being set to true.

If it is set to false, the browser will be frozen. When it recovers, I get "Done!" only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser runs JavaScript and does page rendering all on the same thread, so while JS is running no repaints will occur. This means that your entire for loop will complete and the status message will be set to "Done!" *before* the page gets updated.

In the case of async being true all of the Ajax requests are queued up initially and the message set to "Done!" and then the responses are processed later asynchronously. In the case of async set to false the Ajax requests are done one at a time with no further action until the response comes in. Either way the browser never gets a chance to display the "I am doing..." messages.

Rather than using a loop you can trigger each subsequent call from within the Ajax complete (or success) callback:

```
var tds = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];

function doNextAjax(i) {
   if (i < tds.length) {
      jQuery("#notification-bar").html('I am doing ' + tds[i]);

      jQuery.ajax({
         url: "/ajax_json_echo/",
         type: "POST",
         timeout: 10000,
         data: tds[i],
         success: function(response) {

         },
         error: function(x, t, m) {    

         },
         complete: function() {
            doNextAjax(i + 1);
         }
      });
   } else {
      jQuery("#notification-bar").html("Done!");​
   }
}

doNextAjax(0);
```

Each time `doNextAjax()` is called it updates the status message and makes a single Ajax request and that's all. When the function exits the browser then has a chance to re-render and actually show that message. Then when the complete callback is fired it calls the function again for the next item. When there are no items left it sets the "Done!" message.

Note that using the complete callback to trigger the next Ajax call means that it will keep going even if a particular request fails. If you wanted to stop on error you could get rid of the complete handler and move the `doNextAjax(i+1)` into the success callback.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this is what you use the *success* callback parameter to `ajax()` for - to run a function when the AJAX request completes.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

If you can use HTML5 elements, use the `<progress>` element, this is why he's there.
Increase the progress-bar value in the success callback of each ajax request.

```
var progress = document.getElementById('progress');
progress.max = tds.length;  

...
success: function(){
                       progress.value++;
                   }
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DXYZw/1/)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm using the jquery ui and it does have progress bar feature. And actually, I put the jQuery( "#progress" ).progressbar(  ( i / ( tds.length - 1 ) ) * 100 ); in the success callback

Comment: The "I am doing" notification thing is more important for me.

Comment: @user752492. I just can't understand what is the problem you're facing. Try to show me with a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

The response you wrote will happen. Change

```
jQuery("#notification-bar").html('I am doing ' + tds[i]);
jQuery("#notification-bar").html("Done!");​
```

to

```
jQuery("#notification-bar").append('I am doing ' + tds[i]);
jQuery("#notification-bar").append("Done!");​
```

and you will see result. But, behavior is not what you expect. For loop will fire up all AJAX calls, one after another. If you want to fire up next AJAX call only when the last one is finished you should use [jQuery Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) objects to manage this.

I have wrapped up an example here http://jsfiddle.net/DXYZw/2/

```
var tds = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];

var sendRequest = function(ary, data) {
    if (!ary.length) {
        // no more calls to be made
        jQuery("#notification-bar").append("Done!");
        return;
    }
    jQuery("#notification-bar").append('I am doing ' + tds.length);
    dfAJAX(ary)
        .done(sendRequest)
        .fail(function() {
            alert("error");
        });
}

var dfAJAX = function(ary) {
    var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();

    var dataToSend = ary.pop();

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/ajax_json_echo/",
        type: "POST",
        timeout: 10000,
        data: dataToSend
    })
        .done(function(data) {
            dfd.resolve(ary, data);
        })
        .fail(function() {
            dfd.reject();
        })

    return dfd.promise();
}

sendRequest(tds);
```

Comment: okay, this is another solution. Very cool one. Thanks. I'll take a look at deferred object.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution, you should take a look at jQuery deffered object

```
$.when($.ajax("/page1.php"), $.ajax("/page2.php")).done(function(a1,  a2){
    /* a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the 
        page1 and page2 ajax requests, respectively */
   var jqXHR = a1[2]; /* arguments are [ "success", statusText, jqXHR ] */
   if ( /Whip It/.test(jqXHR.responseText) ) {
      alert("First page has 'Whip It' somewhere.");
   }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/